# Obfuscation and SHAs?

Tags: obfuscation, sha

I'm trying to determine whether it's possible to utilize SHAs for obfuscating and still maintain a decent/full amount of functionality. I'm asking because I can't find anything pertaining to SHAs being used for obfuscating real run-time codes. Every answer I find refers to SHAs for just obfuscating variables into hash for comparison, but not for obfuscating run-time functions and the functionality of the codes.

Thank you everyone and thank you for this lovely site.

Answer (score 0):

Obfuscation is a two way street. You want to be able to both obfuscate something and after deobfuscate and use it.

SHA is a hash function. It's one way street. If you took a hash of something, you can't go back to original value.

As result. You can't use SHA for obfuscation.

BTW. "obfuscating variables into hash" is wrong usage of terminology.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I'm still learning. I'm wondering what would be a hard obfuscation method in your eye? Also I'm currently trying to grasp polymorphic and metamorphics at the moment, so if you you're incline on pinching on these as well on how well they obfuscate code and or any kind of optimization problems, it'll greatly appreciated.